# Ball Occupancy Problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose we put r balls at random in n
boxes, i.e., all n
r assignments of balls to boxes have equal probability. Let Ai be the
event that the ith box is empty and Nn = the number of empty boxes. It is easy to
see that
$P(Ai) = (1 − 1/n)^r$

I'm trying to go through this problem and I do not see how they get 
$P(Ai) = (1 − 1/n)^r$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability that one particular ball does not land in the $i^{th}$ box is $\frac{n-1}{n}$, so the probability that all $r$ balls do not fall in box $i$ is this $\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)\cdots\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)$, where there are $r$ factors, which is $\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^r=\left(1-\frac1n\right)^r$.

Answer (score 0):

The probability that ball 1 lands in box $i$ is $\frac{1}{n}$. So the probability that ball 1 does not land in box $i$ is $1-\frac{1}{n}$.

For all $r$ balls to miss box $i$ you need to multiply $r$ independent events, each with probability i$ is $1-\frac{1}{n}$.

The likelihood that there is any given number $N$ of empty boxes overall is a bit harder to compute.